# It's possible calculate the kernel of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, matlab

I'm trying to calculate the kernel of this matrix in Matlab with this command

```
null(A)
```

But I receive this error

`Empty matrix: 2-by-0`
\begin{bmatrix}
  5&-3\\
  1&1\\
  1&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}

I don't understand why I can't calculate the kernel of this matrix in Matlab

Comment: Do you mean the kernel of its transpose? The null space of the matrix you have given is indeed empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not an error message.

Z = null(A) is an orthonormal basis for the null space of A obtained from the singular value decomposition, in this case, the dimension of the nullspace is $0$. Your matrix has full column rank as we can see that the columns are not multiple of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the column vectors of the given matrix are linearly independent then null space contains only the zero vector $0_{2\times 1}$.